# I want to display tweets with a specific hashtag on the web page in timeline format. But I can't do it Where is the problem?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to display tweets with a specific hashtag on the web page in timeline format. 
But I can't do it
Where is the problem?

```css
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

import tweepy

@app.route("/api/tweet")
def show_tweet():
 api_key=
 api_secret_key=
 access_token=
 access_token_secret=
 auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key,api_secret_key)
 auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
 tweet_url_list=[]
 api=tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=true)
 for tweet in tweepy.cursor.items(10):
  api.search, q= "#nowplaying "+"-filter:retweets"
 tweet_url_list.append(
  f"https://twitter.com/user/status/{tweet.id}")
 response = make_response(
 jsonify(tweet_url_list=tweet_url_list))
 response.cache_control.max_age = 30  
 response.cache_control.s_maxage = 60 
 response.cache_control.public = True 
 return response
```

If possible, please let me know the HTML for posting on the web page.

Comment: What's the problem actually? is it raising an error? have you localized which part isn't working? Try to post specific questions; the more specific the better answers you'll get :)

Comment: In a quick glance, I see a weird indentation (`for tweet in tweepy.cursor.items(10): search and append to list`)